# Should I set argument to pointer to const if it might be changed?

Tags: c, pointers, constants

For example, given a function

```
void func(const int* a, int* b){
    *b = 2 + *a;
}
```

Should I emmit the const if func is often called like so: `func(ptr, ptr)` ?

Comment: You're talking about the declaration of `a`, correct? In which case, yes, you're not changing `a`, so it's okay. You just can't declare the pointers `restrict`.

Comment: You should declare `const` anything that shouldn't change. It is a good practice that will avoid you troubles.

Comment: Probably unrelated: In this case you should pass the integer `a` by value and not as a pointer.

Comment: @mch yeah this just a simpler example to show a real problem I have

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Short answer:

If the function is supposed to be called with the same pointer in both parameters, you should not use `const`. Otherwise, if the function does not support both parameters being the same and what `a` points at shouldn't be modified, the `const` should be there as part of "const correctness".

---

Long answer:

`const` does not guarantee that a pointer is an unique alias. Rather, de-referencing a `const int*` is allowed to be an alias to de-referencing an `int*` as one of the exceptions to the so-called "strict aliasing rule", see the list of exceptions below C17 6.5:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
> the following types:
> ...
>
> - a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object

In practice, check out this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(const int* a, int* b)
{
    int tmp = *a;
    printf("%d\n", tmp);

    *b = 2 + *a;

    tmp = *a;
    printf("%d\n", tmp);
}

int main (void)
{
    int x = 1;
    int* ptr=&x;
    func(ptr,ptr);
    printf("%d\n",*ptr);
}
```

Compiled with gcc 11.2 or clang 14.0.0 x86_64 `-O3`, this prints:

```
1
3
3
```

That is, the value in `tmp` was reloaded since the compiler couldn't assume that the lvalue `*a` was not modified by the previous code.

If we change this code to:

```
void func(const int* restrict a, int* b)
```

Then the output turns into:

```
1
1
3
```

`restrict` is a contract between the compiler and the programmer that all access of what `a` points at goes through the pointer `a`. Since the compiler is now free to assume that `a` and `b` do not alias, it can optimize out the `tmp = *a;` line, since `tmp` already contains the value of `*a`.

In this specific example the programmer lies to the compiler by calling the function as `func(ptr,ptr)` despite arguments being `restrict`ed and the unexpected result of printing 1 inside the function is a bug caused by the caller code.

Comment: Re “If the function is supposed to be called with the same pointer in both parameters, you should not use `const`”: Why?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Because the function writes to the location pointed at by one of the parameters and the pointers may alias. Therefore adding `const` is misleading.

Comment: So there is no technical reason for it. It is an opinion stated without either indicating it is an opinion or giving any supporting reasons for it. It is bad advice because it takes away an advantage of using `const`; the compiler could warn if the pointer is inadvertently used to modify the pointed-to data when the intent of the function is not to do so through that pointer. If there is a desire to document that the function may change the object through another pointer and that the pointers may point to the same object, this may be done through explicit documentation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil No, the correct solution is not make function APIs that take the same pointer as parameter twice. That's common sense.

Comment: There are valid reasons for a function to have parameters that might or might not overlap, such as signal processing routines where the caller might or might not want the output to be written into one of the input buffers. It is a caller option, and it is entirely reasonable to mark the inputs as `const` and the output as not and to support calling the routine both with and without overlaps.

Comment: @Lundin I am currently dealing with a problem were the 2 arguments passed in may be differnet or the same.

Answer (score 1):

The word `const` in your function definition documents that the function will not change the object whose address is passed as the first argument to the function. It says that `a` is a pointer to a "constant integer".

So if your function does not change the object that `a` points to, it makes sense to keep the `const`.

While it is not necessary to include the `const`, it is good practice to do so. If you do not intend to change the object that `a` points to but your code attempts to modify `*a` anyways, this should be an error that your compiler will detect.

Comment: I tried my code out, and it didn't result in an error... I am talking about a situation were the 2 argument are identical, and thus changing *b = *a changes *a